# Getting GPS coordinates on Windows phone 7

Tags: gps, windows-phone-7

How can I get the current GPS coordinates on Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;

watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default)
                   {
                       MovementThreshold = 20
                   };

watcher.PositionChanged += this.watcher_PositionChanged;
watcher.StatusChanged += this.watcher_StatusChanged;
watcher.Start();


private void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Status)
    {
        case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
            // location is unsupported on this device
            break;
        case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
            // data unavailable
            break;
    }
}

private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    var epl = e.Position.Location;

    // Access the position information thusly:
    epl.Latitude.ToString("0.000");
    epl.Longitude.ToString("0.000");
    epl.Altitude.ToString();
    epl.HorizontalAccuracy.ToString();
    epl.VerticalAccuracy.ToString();
    epl.Course.ToString();
    epl.Speed.ToString();
    e.Position.Timestamp.LocalDateTime.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

[GeoCoordinateWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher%28VS.92%29.aspx) is the class that provides this functionality. There is a [How To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431782%28VS.92%29.aspx), a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28VS.92%29.aspx) and some other [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431803%28VS.92%29.aspx) on MSDN.