# How to track distance accurately between two locations in windows phone using GPS?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am working on location tracking app. App is showing the current location in the beginning and later it is displaying incorrect values and the code is as follows. It draws a line(animated line) on the Map tracking our location and it is showing wrong path. Though device is at constant place, it is displaying wrong values. Did I miss anything?

```
 //code        

         public partial class Walk : PhoneApplicationPage
            {            
              private GeoCoordinateWatcher _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
                private MapPolyline _line;
                private DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                private long _startTime;       

                public Walk()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    _line = new MapPolyline();
                    _line.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
                    _line.StrokeThickness = 5;
                    Map.MapElements.Add(_line);

                    _watcher.Start();

                    _timer.Start();
                    _startTime = System.Environment.TickCount;

                    _watcher.PositionChanged += Watcher_PositionChanged;

                    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
                }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    TimeSpan runTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(System.Environment.TickCount - _startTime);
                    timeLabel.Text = runTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                }


         private double _kilometres;



                private long _previousPositionChangeTick;


                private void Watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
                {

                    var coord = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);

                    if (_line.Path.Count > 0)
                    {                
                        var previousPoint = _line.Path.Last();
                        var distance = coord.GetDistanceTo(previousPoint);
                        var millisPerKilometer = (1000.0 / distance) * (System.Environment.TickCount - _previousPositionChangeTick);
                        _kilometres += distance / 1000.0;               
                        paceLabel.Text = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisPerKilometer).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
                        distanceLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:f2} km", _kilometres);
                        caloriesLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:f0}", _kilometres * 65);

                        PositionHandler handler = new PositionHandler();
                        var heading = handler.CalculateBearing(new Position(previousPoint), new Position(coord));
                        Map.SetView(coord, Map.ZoomLevel, heading, MapAnimationKind.Parabolic);

              }
              else
              {
                Map.Center = coord;
              }

              _line.Path.Add(coord);
              _previousPositionChangeTick = System.Environment.TickCount;
            }          

            }  }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are the "incorrect values" within a few dozen meters of the original location? If so, what you might be seeing is just the inaccuracy of GPS.

GPS isn't 100% accurate. Even if your device isn't moving, the location where the device's GPS  *thinks it is* can change. In fact, your calculated location might not be based on true GPS at all, but on Wi-Fi or on nearby cell towers (A-GPS), both of which are much less accurate.

See [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281383/windows-phone-7-geocoordinatewatcher-accuracy) for more information. For debugging purposes, I suggest displaying the [HorizontalAccuracy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.horizontalaccuracy.aspx) somewhere on your UI to see if the GPS drift is in line with expectations.

Comment: I've already tried in outdoor location. It's working fine. It's not accurate in the indoor. That's the problem. Thank u.