# GeoCoordinateWatcher is not getting GeoCoordinate Speed in emulator?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I'm trying out a Windows Phone 7 Maps application which tracks the device. I'm displaying a textblock which updates the current speed using "e.Position.Location.Speed.ToString("0.00")" from the "GeoPositionChangedEventArgs e" argument passed to the PositionChanged event handler of "GeoCoordinateWatcher" object.

While debugging the application in emulator, I used a set of previously recorded push pins and played the emulation. The longitude/lattitude positions change properly but the speed is reflected as NAN.

Why is this happening? How is the speed property calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving you call to separate thread will fixed the problem...

[GeoCoordinateWatcher location not returning speed. NaN instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175079/geocoordinatewatcher-location-not-returning-speed-nan-instead)