# How to get Speed from GeoCoordinate

Tags: c#, wpf, gmap.net

I am using `GMap.Net` to add ellipses as marker on map at runtime. ToolTip property of each ellipse is set to display Time and Speed when Added. Instead of number as speed I get NaN always.

On Timer's elapsed event `Addellipse` method is called -

```
void Addellipse(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        getInfo = GetLocationProperty();
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse()
        {
            Fill = Brushes.Black,
            ToolTip = getInfo.CurrentTime + "\n" + getInfo.CurrentSpeed,
            Height = 7,
            Width = 7
        };

        GMapMarker marker = new GMapMarker(getInfo.CurrentPosition)
        {
            Shape = ellipse,
            ZIndex = int.MaxValue
        };

        MapControl.Markers.Add(marker);
        MapControl.Position = getInfo.CurrentPosition;
    });
}
```

`GetLocationProperty` returns `ToolTipInfo`

```
ToolTipInfo GetLocationProperty()
{
    coord = watcher.Position.Location;
    if (!coord.IsUnknown)
    {
        returnlatlon.Lat = coord.Latitude;
        returnlatlon.Lng = coord.Longitude;
        tooltipInfo.CurrentPosition = returnlatlon;
        tooltipInfo.CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        tooltipInfo.CurrentSpeed = coord.Speed.ToString();
    }
    return tooltipInfo;
}
```

here is the `ToolTipInfo`

```
public class ToolTipInfo
{
    public PointLatLng CurrentPosition { get; set; }
    public string CurrentTime { get; set; }
    public string CurrentSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

and my `watcher` is initialized in this way in constructor

```
watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
watcher.TryStart(true, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
```

How can I get speed?

Comment: Did you ensure that more than one position was recorded, before  trying to access speed? I don't know if speed is automatically managed by the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` but I do know that no speed can be calculated from a single location.

Comment: @grek40  I expected to get that automatically! Do I have to store two consecutive location for calculating speed manually like - divide distance between two location by the difference of corresponding time?

Comment: Do you retrieve the Location data in a `GeoCoordinateWatcher.PositionChanged` event handler or synchronously in the UI thread? [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9258193/1136211).

Comment: @Clemens `coord` is `GeoCoordinate` initialized once in constructor and used in `GetLocationProperty` method. It updates with new location data everytime It is called by `Addellipse `. I did not consider using `GeoCoordinateWatcher.PositionChanged`. So it should be in UI thread I think.

Comment: You should at least try if you actually get valid speed values in a PositionChanged handler. As far as I understood the linked Q/A, Speed may always be NaN when you directly access the Location property (not sure however if that is still true).

Comment: @Clemens I have added `watcher.PositionChanged += Watcher_PositionChanged` in constructor, Still I get NaN in `GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e` of `Watcher_PositionChanged`

Comment: And your device is actually moving?

Comment: That's certainly below the threshold to determine a real speed. It has to move continuously for a couple of position fixes.

Comment: well, I'll try it in car after an hour @Clemens. Thanks for the information.

Comment: What kind of device is it, does it even have a GPS receiver? Not sure if you get any speed at all when position is detected from WiFi hotspot locations.

Comment: It is hp laptop @Clemens

Comment: No GPSR I guess. Without that, determining speed is pointless. You may check the Location's `HorizontalAccuracy` property to get an idea.

Comment: It gives `HoriontalAccuracy` as number but NaN  for `Course`, `VerticalAccuracy` and `Speed` @Clemens

Comment: Sure, but what is the value of HoriontalAccuracy?

Comment: Last time it was 69 @Clemens

Comment: That means you don't have a GPSR. With it, accuracy is a few meters. You can't get speed values without GPS.

Comment: As I was moving along the road it added markers along with time almost in right position on the map for 20 km past @Clemens, is it possible without GPSR?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What is "almost in right position", and was that in a city with a lot of known WiFi hotspots? Without GPS it won't work reliably, at least not outside inhabited areas.

Comment: It added markers very close to the streets I have past to come back to home. I am in Dhaka, Bangladesh @Clemens

Comment: If that is what you need. I can't tell you if your application does what you want.

Comment: I have tried to add an ellipse on the map after every 10 sec and wanted to get the time and speed from those ellipses as tooltip. Ellipses were added correctly and when I hover over an ellipse I get a tooltip like `8:00 PM NaN`, I expected to get Speed insted of NaN  @Clemens

Comment: I have understood that. It is what we are talking about all the time. However, I can't tell if the position accuracy you get right now is sufficient, or meets your expectation. Let's stop the discussion now.