# How to get two geo coordinates using location service in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, location

I Want to Calculate the distance between two geo coordinates obtained using location service in windows phone .i have given two buttons (i.e start and stop ) in my main page . i want to capture the then current coordinate when i press start and store it in some variable , and the then current coordinate when i press the stop and Store it in another variable. How can i do it . can i get the code for it .Thank you .

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712763/getting-gps-coordinates-on-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681887.aspx). I hope you will find what you are looking for. Or you can try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712763/getting-gps-coordinates-on-windows-phone-7)