# Query is related to Windows Phone 7 coding

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have downloaded the GPS code from Codeproject.com.
I want to track my current location.
In the codeproject code, it is able to find the location,but i have to enter the latitude and longitude in my code,which is hard coded.

I want that to dynamically happen in code.

For example:- if i enter in code latitude = 19.1767; longitude = 73.0222; then this will take me to Mumbai.
But to track his current location,user wont go in code and enter the latitude and longitude.
How can it happen dynamically??
Please help..

Thanks & Regards
Hasib Shaikh

Comment: Just http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712763/getting-gps-coordinates-on-windows-phone-7 ?

Comment: Please refer this link. I guess it should answer your question. http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/13/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-13-location-services/